# How to correctly checkout branches from a remote repository

Tags: git

I have this

```
    abc@abc-ubuntu:~/project1/wh-app-ios$ git branch -a -v -v
    * master                   1d35af1 [origin/master: ahead 2] Adding 123 to hello
      remotes/gitb/gh-pages    e3dad9d boom
      remotes/gitb/integration 1d3fcd5 Adding 55_Glossary chapter
      remotes/gitb/master      86d1d30 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'
      remotes/gitb/pt_BR       dc9d991 Revisions at 03, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11 and 50
      remotes/origin/HEAD      -> origin/master
      remotes/origin/master    1ae426b Update README.md
```

I do

```
    abc@abc-ubuntu:~/project1/wh-app-ios$ git checkout gitb/master
    Note: checking out 'gitb/master'.

    You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
    changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
    state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

    If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
    do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

      git checkout -b new_branch_name

    HEAD is now at 86d1d30... Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'
```

Then looking at the cautionary message above I do

```
    abc@abc-ubuntu:~/project1/wh-app-ios$ git checkout -b mastergitb
    Switched to a new branch 'mastergitb'
```

Now I am at

```
    abc@abc-ubuntu:~/project1/wh-app-ios$ git branch -a -v -v
      master                   1d35af1 [origin/master: ahead 2] Adding 123 to hello
    * mastergitb               86d1d30 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'
      remotes/gitb/gh-pages    e3dad9d boom
      remotes/gitb/integration 1d3fcd5 Adding 55_Glossary chapter
      remotes/gitb/master      86d1d30 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'
      remotes/gitb/pt_BR       dc9d991 Revisions at 03, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11 and 50
      remotes/origin/HEAD      -> origin/master
      remotes/origin/master    1ae426b Update README.md
    abc@abc-ubuntu:~/project1/wh-app-ios$
```

Question:

1. But clearly mastergitb is not tracking gitb/master. Why is that ?
2. Did I just create a local branch named mastergitb that is simply a copy of gitb/master but has no other relation with it ?

Comment: BTW, what is "gitb"? Just a typo for "git"?

Comment: @sleske no, it is the name of a remote repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a peculiar thing about a "remote branch", as git calls them, that makes them very different from "local" branches.  I sometimes think it might make more sense to people if git used a different name, although I don't actually have a better name.  So, with respect to question 2:

> Did I just create a local branch named `mastergitb` that is simply a copy of `gitb/master` but has no other relation with it ?

Yes, but the phrase "a copy of" is a bit misleading.  Say, instead, that you created a local branch that *ends at the same commit as* the remote one.

The thing to keep in mind about git branches is that each branch name is just a *label for a commit*.  What makes a local branch name particularly special (and useful) is that it's a *moving* label, and it moves *automatically*.  (Compare with a "tag", which is also a label for a particular commit, but tags do not move automatically, and people generally expect them to stay put.  You have to warn others who share or copy from your repo if you move a tag.)

When you're "on a branch"—as opposed to having a "detached HEAD", which as someone noted, is kind of gruesome—and you make a new commit, the branch label automatically moves to the new commit.  That is, when `HEAD` is a name for branch `bran`, `git commit` (and `git merge` and the other various other ways to add commits) add the new commit, with its parent pointing to the previous branch-tip, and then move the branch-tip forward:

```
C5 -- C6 -- C7   <-- HEAD=bran
```

becomes:

```
C5 -- C6 -- C7 -- C8   <-- HEAD=bran
```

But "remote branches" don't work like this.  In fact, you can't even be "on" a remote branch, as you discovered: if you `git checkout origin/master`, git puts you into that "detached HEAD" state.

The other funny thing, though, is that "remote branches" *can and do move*.  They don't move when *you* add a commit, because you're never "on" them.  You check them out and your head is guillotined right off. :-)  You can then create a local branch, with `git checkout -b`, just as you did.  This local branch is set to point to the commit that `HEAD` names, which is the same commit that the "remote branch name" points-to.  It's not quite a copy of anything, because it's just an arrow *pointing to* a commit.

In diagram form, it might look a bit like this (assuming you're on a local `master` that is "tracking" `origin/master`):

```
       C2        <-- origin/xyz
      /
C0--C1           <-- origin/foo
      \
       C3--C4    <-- origin/bar
         \
          C5     <-- origin/master, HEAD=master
```

If you `git checkout origin/foo`, git will erase the `HEAD=` from the bottom (leaving `origin/master` and `master` both pointing to commit `C5`), and set `HEAD` to the SHA-1 hash for commit `C1`.  It doesn't set `HEAD=origin/foo` (which would put you "on" the remote branch), but rather, directly to the commit hash (the "detached head" state).

Then, when you `git checkout -b localfoo`, git creates a new branch name `localfoo`, sets it to point to commit `C1`, and sets `HEAD=localfoo`.  Now you're "on a branch"!

Note: the "full name" of a local branch `bran` is `refs/heads/bran`.  The "full name" of a remote branch `rmt/bran` is `refs/remotes/rmt/bran`.  That is, a local branch is always in `refs/heads/`, and a remote one never is.  Normally you leave all the front-end stuff out and just refer to `bran` and `origin/bran`, but sometimes it matters, and it makes some of the text below make more sense.

Aside from making `localfoo` "track" `origin/foo` (already answered), there's one more item to explain, and that is: how, exactly, do "remote branches" move?  The answer: they move on a `git fetch` (or `git remote update` which is basically the same as `fetch`).  When you fetch (or update) from a remote, git contacts the remote and finds its branch names.  Using those names, it finds the commits to which they point.  Then it finds their parents, and their parents' parents, and so on.  Whenever you don't have those commits, it brings them over and stuffs them into your repo, so that you "catch up" to the remote.  Then it writes the new reference names under the "remote branches" category, as controlled by the `.git/config` file.

If you peek in `.git/config` you'll see something like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = ssh://some.where.out.there/some/path/to/repo.git
```

That `fetch` line is the key to getting the "remote branches".  It says that, for everything the remote has that matches `refs/heads/*`—all of *its* local branches—replace `refs/heads/` with `refs/remotes/origin/` (keeping the rest of the branch name) and then update those refs (forcibly, because of the `+` sign).  So, after someone controlling the remote URL updates that repo, and then you `fetch` from them, you get their updates, and your git moves your "remote branch" labels to match.

It's up to you whether and when to move your *local* branch labels to match the automatically-moved "remote branch" labels.  The easy way to do that is by using "git merge", and the easy way to automate that is to make the local branch a "tracking branch".  Once you've marked local branch *L* as tracking remote branch *rmt/R*, `git status` will tell you if it is behind, `git pull` will know how to invoke `git merge`, and `git merge` can be told to auto-update (see `merge.defaultToUpstream` in the CONFIGURATION section of the [git-merge documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)).

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure why the message doesn't refer to this, but you can write

```
git checkout -t origin/branchname
```

to create a local branch named `branchname` that tracks `origin/branchname` (`-t` is short for `--track`). Or you can write

```
git checkout -b localname -t origin/branchname
```

to create a local branch named `localname` that tracks `origin/branchname`, so in your example:

```
git checkout -b mastergitb -t gitb/master
```

Yes, creating a non-tracking branch is exactly what you did. You can fix it by deleting the branch and following these instructions, or by running `git branch --set-upstream mastergitb gitb/master` to set the upstream for the existing branch.